# Meaning of "leibe" as an adjective

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I understand that the German noun *Leibe* translates to *womb* in English, but can make neither head nor tail of its possible meaning if used as an adjective. Here is the sentence it is used in:

> Er muß sich selber sehr leibe gefühlt haben an dieser Stelle.

So, in English:

> He must have felt very ____ himself at this point.

What is the meaning of this adjective? (Given the context which can be seen in the links I assume it may be some kind of pun.)

Full context [here](http://www.zeit.de/1976/06/zum-schreien-schwierig/seite-3) or [here](http://www.d-e-zimmer.de/HTML/1976ulysses.htm) (first may require a sign-up). Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Leibe` (Leib) means `Körper`, can also be `Bauch` (compare: duden.de), but not generally `womb`.
`Ein Kind im Leibe tragen` is poetic / antiquated language, it means to be pregnant, maybe `heavy with child` (or a similar expression).

On the other hand, in the given context (translation of the word `womb`), `Leib` isn’t such a bad translation. It could also be `Mutterleib` or `Schoß`.

In this case, the author uses the fictitious adjective `leibe` (as in `sich leibe fühlen`) to criticise the translator of that passage, maybe because he considers the choice of the word inadequate.

You could try `womby` for your fill-in-the-blanks.

This is the original passage:

> In what posture?
>
> Listener: reclined semilaterally, left, left hand under head, right
>   leg extended in a straight line and resting on left leg, flexed, in
>   the attitude of Gea-Tellus, fulfilled, recumbent, big with seed.
>   Narrator: reclined laterally, left, with right and left legs flexed,
>   the index finger and thumb of the right hand resting on the bridge of
>   the nose, in the attitude depicted in a snapshot photograph made by
>   Percy Apjohn, the childman weary, the manchild in the womb.
>
> Womb? Weary?
>
> He rests. He has travelled.
>
> With?
>
> Sinbad the Sailor and Tinbad the Tailor and Jinbad the Jailer and
>   Whinbad the Whaler and Ninbad the Nailer and Finbad the Failer and
>   Binbad the Bailer and Pinbad the Pailer and Minbad the Mailer and
>   Hinbad the Hailer and Rinbad the Railer and Dinbad the Kailer and
>   Vinbad the Quailer and Linbad the Yailer and Xinbad the Phthailer.

And this is the write-up:

> Das vorletzte Kapitel ("Ithaka"), im Stile eines wissenschaftlichen
>   Katechismus geschrieben, endet mit einer der poetischsten Stellen der
>   Literatur: Blooms kleiner und doch großer, großmütiger Geist sinkt weg
>   in den Schlaf: "… der Kindmann müde, das Mannkind im Mutterschoß.
>   Mutterschoß? Müde? Er ruht. Er ist gereist. Mit? Sindbad dem Seefahrer
>   und Tindbad dem Teefahrer ..." So heißt es jetzt bei Wollschläger. Bei
>   Goyert aber stand: "... der müde Kindmensch, das Menschkind im Leibe.
>   Leibe? Müde? Er ruht. Er hat gereist. Mit? Sindbad dem Seefahrer und
>   Tindbad ." Er muß sich selber sehr leibe gefühlt haben an dieser
>   Stelle.